# How to integrate Paypal for no Paypal customers?

Tags: paypal

My client asks me to integrate Paypal for no Paypal users which means:

- they directly insert their card data (no messages such as : "you don't have a Paypal account yet, so create it now"
- as few references to Paypal (no Paypal logo, no Paypal headers)

I have integrate  Paypal many times, but the integration invites users to use Paypal, shows Paypal logo, Paypal url etc.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

[PayPal Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/) has an option for 'Debit or Credit Card', which works for most countries.

Here's a code demo: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

Comment: yes looks close. But this has also the PAYPAL button which I want to remove: I want to keep ONLY Credit Card button

Comment: This is the service PayPal offers, where customers get an equal choice of signing into an account that has saved payment information or entering card details manually, whichever they prefer